# Raspberry Pi Sense Hat

Tags: python, multithreading, bash, raspberry-pi, multiprocessing

Trying to use the sense hat with the `raspberry pi` to monitor the temp in a room and stream the data to plot.ly. I have that all working fine. The next step was to add the `Picamera` to the project so when the temp reached a certain point the camera will turn on and started to record pictures every 5 minutes while still streaming the data to plot.ly. I created the scripts separately and run them from a bash script to background, but the problem is the data is getting "mixed up" and giving the wrong temperature. I was looking at subprocess but it stops one of the scripts running. How can I run both at the same time and won't affect each other so I'll stream the data live and the camera will take pictures if the condition is met?

Here's my code for data stream:

```
##### Main Program #####
sense = SenseHat()
sense.clear()

####Graph####
stream_id = 'nync7etjej'

stream = dict(token=stream_id,maxpoints=60)
trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x =[],
    y=[],
    mode='lines+markers',
    stream=stream)
data= go.Data([trace1])

layout =go.Layout(title='Room Temperature')

fig = go.Figure(data=data,layout=layout)
py.plot(fig,filename="Server Room Temperature_01")

s = py.Stream(stream_id)

s.open()

time.sleep(5)

while True:
    temp_h= sense.get_temperature()
    temp_h=round(temp_h,1)
    x=datetime.now()
    y=temp_h   
    s.write(dict(x=x,y=y))
    time.sleep(300)    
s.close()
tls.embed('Streaming Temp','12')
```

Picamera script:

```
##### Main Program #####
sense = SenseHat()
sense.clear()
with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:

    while True:
        temp_h= sense.get_temperature()
        temp_h=round(temp_h,1)
        if temp_h >45.2:
            camera.start_preview()
            time.sleep(2)
            for filename in camera.capture_continuous('/var/www/image/img{counter}.jpg'):
                camera.stop_preview()
                time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to avoid two programs accessing the SenseHAT at once.  There are lots of sophisticated ways of doing that, with shared memory and semaphores and things.

One very simple method though, is to leave your temperature monitoring script as it is, but when you read the temperature, if it is above 45.2, create an empty file called "/HOT", and if it is below that, delete the file "/HOT".

Then, in the camera script, run a loop that checks if the file "/HOT" exists and starts/stops the camera accordingly.

That way, only one process will be reading the SenseHAT.

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell that seems to be doing the job. The finally problem is that I can't get the camera to stop once the 'Hot' file is deleted. I have if not os.path.exists('Hot') then camera.close but that isn't working as i think it's stuck in the loop now as true.